# Incorrect logo positioning on Chrome on first page load

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, positioning

See: http://hurstenigma.co.uk

My logo is positioned correctly on IE and Firefox (I haven't tested other browsers yet), however on Chrome it seems to be miles above the other elements on the page for no good reason. The logo does fall back into the correct position once the page is soft reloaded (I click the URL and press enter).

This wasn't happening originally and I can't figure out what change I made to cause this to happen. My search of the internet has be fruitless as this does not seem to be a documented problem.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks, 
Robert

Answer (score 2):

```
#logo {
    float: left;
}
```

Maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Float left like FSou1 said, but also add to your `ul#navbar` element:

```
padding: 0;
```